# find path of pull along toy

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry

Imagine a child pulling a pull along toy. The toy will always be in a fixed distance $l$ (length of the string) away from the child.

Lets say a child's position is given by $c:[0,T] \to \mathbb R^2$. We are looking for the toys position $p:(0,T]\to \mathbb R^2$ given a valid initial position $p(0) \in \mathbb R^2$.

How can we find $p$?

Obviously, $p$ must be some kind of pursuit curve but it is not a radiodrome, as the velocities are not constant (but the distance is).

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer but a suggestion. I suppose that the motion is in a plane.

Suppose the child is in $A=(x_A(t),y_A(t))$ and the toy in $B=(x_B(t),y_B(t))$.

The string can transmit only traction in the direction $AB$ so the first step is to find the component in this direction of the child acceleration $\vec a=(\ddot x_A(t),\ddot y_A(t) )$.  We have: $\vec{AB}=(x_B-x_A,y_B-y_A)$ so we find:
$$
a_{AB}=\dfrac{\langle\vec a\,,\vec {AB}\rangle \vec{AB}}{|\vec {AB}|}=\langle \vec a\,,\vec u\rangle \vec u
$$
where $\vec u$ is the versor of $\vec {AB}$.
But this acceleration is transmitted to $B$ only if it is positive, so we can write the acceleration $\vec b$ of $B$ as:

$$
\vec b= \dfrac{1}{2}\left(\langle \vec a\,,\vec u\rangle +|\langle \vec a\,,\vec u\rangle| \right) \vec u
$$
and, with given inital condition, we can write a second order differential equation for $(x_B,y_B)$.

Comment: Thank you very much so far! I have a few questions: What do you mean by *versor*? And as you only used the derivatives of $A$, I think it does not result in a differential equation but rather just a functional equation with respect to $B$? (Because $A$ is known but $B$ isn't.)

Comment: the *versor*is the **unitary** vector of direction $\vec {AB}$. Really you have  two differential equations when you write $\ddot x_b= \vec b_x$ and $\ddot y_b= \vec b_y$. The componets of  $\vec a$ are know functions since the motion of the child is given.